# What is this symbol and does it relate to FMA?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

When I was searching for Fullmetal Alchemist wallpapers this image came up (below).

I was wondering what this symbol is? And does it have any relation to the FMA anime or manga universes?

[image: Symbol]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image represents a [transmutation array](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemy#Transmutation_Array), the [Grand Arcanum](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Arcanum).
A transmutation array is similar to a [transmutation circle](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemy#Transmutation_Circle), and also has the function of allowing for the energy to circulate during a transmutation. They differ, however, in the fact that the runes (drawings) that compose the array may exceed the limits of the circle.

This array is exclusive to the 2003 anime, and is used by Scar to make a philosopher's stone using the souls of the people of Reole.